# backspace and tab is not working for firefox

Tags: angularjs

**Html file**

```
 <input type="text" reg-ex-input reg-ex="^[a-zA-Z\t]+$"  name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="module.mod_name" >
```

***custom directives***

```
app.directive('regExInput', function(){
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          require: '?regEx',
          scope: {},
          replace: false,
          link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
              var regex = new RegExp(attrs.regEx);
              var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
              if (!regex.test(key)) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 return false;
              }
            });
          }
      };
  });
```

Tab and backspace are not working for firefox .....for other browser its working fine.Reason may be firefox considered tab and backspace as special character...So what should i do now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, Firefox is triggering the `keypress` event for Tab and Backspace, whereas Chrome (at least) is not.

You can change your `link` function to the following:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
  element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp(attrs.regEx);
    var charCode = !event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode;
    // check for tab & backspace for Firefox:
    if ([0, 8].indexOf(charCode) !== -1) return;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

[See it working at Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/h3rZWGOvov8zO9XHMBD7?p=preview)

Comment: Great. You should accept the answer, then (by clicking the checkmark by the up/down votes), so that others know it has been resolved successfully.

Comment: for file upload i need some help.......i am using angular js at frontend and nodejs and express as backend

Comment: If you can't figure out file upload then I'd recommend making a separate question describing your issue. That way more people will look at it than here in these comments.